# Weird Thread exception when using Dispatcher.BeginInvoke in a thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, dispatcher

I'm running a pretty time-consuming method in a thread, and one of the things it does, is if there is no image available it sets a grid named Background's background to a solid color. Here's how that snippet looks:

```
SolidColorBrush scb = new SolidColorBrush();
scb.Color = Color.FromRgb(21, 21, 21);
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => Background.Background = scb));
```

But I always get errors at this place saying `"Cannot use a DependencyObject that belongs to a different thread than its parent Freezable"`

Does anyone know why this is happening? The Dispatcher should make this problem go away, right?

Here's how I am calling the method by the way (if needed)

```
Thread BGthread = new Thread(HandleBackgrounds);
BGthread.Start();
```

Comment: In what context is `Dispatcher`?  In a `Form`?  A property that you've copied from a `Form`?

Comment: It's in a WPF page, the dispatcher works fine otherwise, I even use it two other times in the same method. That is why it's so surprising it doesn't work with this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`SolidColorBrush` is a dependency object - and you're creating it in the non-UI thread, then trying to use it in the UI thread. Try this instead:

```
Action action = () =>
{
    SolidColorBrush scb = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(21, 21, 21));
    Background.Background = scb;
};
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(action);
```

Or of course just in one statement:

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action (() =>
    Background.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(21, 21, 21)))));
```

Either way, you're creating the `SolidColorBrush` in the action that you're passing to the dispatcher.

Comment: Ah!! I did not realize. Thank you so much for the help :)

Answer (score 2):

A `Brush` is a `DispatcherObject`, and as such it has a thread affinity - it belongs to the thread that created it, and normally can only be used by it.

However, WPF has a sub-class of dispatcher objects, called `Freezable`s, for which you can remove the thread affinity by making them read-only. Brushes are freezable, so you can create one on a thread and pass it to another:

```
var scb = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(21, 21, 21));
scb.Freeze();
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => Background.Background = scb));
```

This can be useful if you're creating a brush in a view model that's not created on a UI thread. Another common use case is decoding images on a different thread, which can improve performance (`ImageSource` is also a freezable).

Freezing freezables is also considered a [performance optimization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613565.aspx), so use it whenever possible.